# Struts Tiles Freemarker InvalidReferenceException pointing to Struts2 error.ftl as cause

Tags: java, exception, struts2, freemarker

I'm implementing a new Struts 2 action and now I'm getting the following exception:

```
Error executing FreeMarker template: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> rootloc.URI  [in template "org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/error.ftl" at line 86, column 15]
```

Struts Tiles tries to show our custom error page but during that process encounters above exception. It somehow can't set a property within the error.ftl which is delivered by the Struts framework itself. Hence the error page is not shown.

I have checked the error.ftl and the problem seems to occur somewhere around here (reference: https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/error.ftl):

```
<tr>
        <td><strong>File</strong>:</td>
        <td>${rootloc.URI}</td>
</tr>
```

Did anyone encounter this or a similar problem? I have no idea how to fix this because the error occurs within a Struts 2 component and I have no chance of debugging. I'm using Struts Version 2.3.36.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Debugging your code is very similar to debugging 3rd party code. Anyway, from the source code what seems to happen is that the template wants to print the file name for the exception. But `LocationUtils.getLocale(exception)` returns a `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.location.Location` where `getURI()` returns `null`. I guess the template should expect that, as the Location `API` allows that. But it doesn't, so it fails at that `null`. If you can modify the template it's easy to fix. Otherwise it's a good starting point for a bug report.

Comment: @ddekany thanks, I'll see if I can somehow modify the template. Otherwise I'll prepare a bug report

Comment: Regarding fixing the template, there's something like `${rootloc.URI}` in it, and that need to be replaced with `${rootloc.URI!'Unknown'}`.

Comment: How do you replace `${rootloc.URI}` with `${rootloc.URI}!'Unknown'`? @ddekany

Comment: @KavinRajuS I meant, instead of `${rootloc.URI}` OP could write `${rootloc.URI!'Unknown'}`.